# Can't access specific element using xpath with selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I am trying to parse the wind direction using selenium and I think using xpath is the easiest way to get this info.
There is a table with all the information and the xpath of the elements within this table follow the same structure, hence my following code:

```
wind_directions = [browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="archive_results"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[{i}]').text for i in range(14,25)]
```

Indeed, the structure of the data on the site is the following:
[image: Data structure in the table]

My issue is that I would like to get the content "rotate(494, 50, 50) translate(0,5)" from the picture above but I can't:
If I try to write replace the previous fstring with `f'//*[@id="archive_results"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[{i}]/svg/g']`,
The compiler tells me that `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="archive_results"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[14]/svg/g"}`.

Any idea why I get such a message while this is the exact xpath that appears when I check on the element on Chrome ? (I triple-checked the indexes in the fstring and it is not the source of the error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svg` `g` etc. are special tag names.
To locate such nodes with XPath you can change your XPath expression as following:

```py
'//*[@id="archive_results"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[{i}]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]'
```